# When Refreshing the website it stays in a # link and it doesnt go back to the main # HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

So i have one website and it has a button, the button sends you to section number 2, then when i refresh the website it stays in the section 2 but i want it to go to the main sections, please help me! Have a nice day.

```html
<section class="Hero" id="#sec-1">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="Name">
         <h1 class="logo">Darius Rücker</h1>
         <div class="Slogan">
            <H4 class="textSlogan">Think. Contact. <span class="Mark">Create.</span> </H4>
         </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#sec-2">
         <div class="scroll-down"></div>
      </a>
   </div>
   <div class="container">
      <div class="Neon">
         <span class="textoNeon">hola</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
<section class="next" id="sec-2">
   <h1>HEY</h1>
</section>
```

```css
.scroll-down {
    height: 50px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
  
}
```

Comment: unfortunately you cant do that without having some javascript to remove the # from the url

Comment: Notice what happens to the URL when you click your link

Comment: I did notice, the # changes, I don't know how to remove it or change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the id from the url right after the user click on the anchor tag

`history.scrollRestoration = "manual"` will set the scroll to the top of the page on refresh

```html
<a onclick="removeAnchorFormURL()" href="#sec-2">here</a>

<script>
  history.scrollRestoration = "manual";

  const removeAnchorFormURL = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.history.replaceState({}, "", window.location.href.split("#")[0]);
    }, 100);
  };
</script>
```

[window.location docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

[location.href docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href)

[location.replace docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace)

[scrollRestoration docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/scrollRestoration) (check it for info on scrollRestoration compatibility)

Comment: Hey, Thanks! could you please help me by sending me some kind of resource to know exactly what the js is doing?

Comment: Added the link to the answer

Comment: there is something wrong with the code

Comment: There are no errors in the code, where are you running it?

Comment: VSC, I'm not sure if there is an error or I just need to add some kind of imput, what happens is that when I press the button it doesn't take me to the second section, it stays in the main one and when I scroll down manually to section 2 and I refresh the page it just goes up 1 pixel.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are trying to run?

Comment: Sure no problem, here you have my github link: https://github.com/Darius17TARS/Website

Comment: Found a better solution that fixes your problem, edited my answer.